# Set combobox items dynamically based on search query

Tags: java, combobox, vaadin

I have a combobox that I would like to act as a search field. When I enter some value I want to call a backend service that would based on the entered value return a list of possible values. I would like to set these values as the combobox items dynamically. So far I have this code:

```
ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>("Name");
comboBox.setAllowCustomValue(true);
comboBox.setAutofocus(true);
comboBox.addCustomValueSetListener(e -> comboBox.setItems(backendService.getData(e.getValue())));
```

This works, but it is not ideal, as I (the user) has to type the value, hit enter and focus the combobox again. At this point the matched values from backend are set as items in the combobox. Is there a way to fetch items from the backend dynamically as the user writes in the input with some time delay (e.g. `ValueChangeMode.LAZY` for `TextField`) and set them as combobox items while writing user input?

Comment: You mean loading the data lazy from the backend? Read this. https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/binding-data/data-provider#lazy-data-binding-using-callbacks

Comment: If you want an "autocomplete" field, you should look into the directory - there are options available https://vaadin.com/directory/search?keyword=auto

Comment: Lazy loading data for combobox worked for me.

Comment: @MichaelKročka Great, that you found your own solution.  SO is a FAQ page and it's fine to anwer and accept your own question.  This will help others with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through [this link](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/binding-data/data-provider#lazy-data-binding-using-callbacks) I found a solution using lazy data loading. I had to adjust my backend service to accept a `PageRequest` object, so the following line of code did exactly what I wanted:

```
comboBox.setItems(query -> 
    backendService.getData(PageRequest.of(query.getPage(), query.getPageSize())));
```